# Pull input items from a different form on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I am not as well versed in JavaScript as I would like but I am still learning. I have a simple page with a form for a user to put in various pieces of information and then once the submit button is clicked, it will display an overlay popup with a configuration using the items they input. However, I am not sure how to use multiple forms without having the need for the user to put the information in twice. Essentially, I will have multiple submit buttons that generate different configurations but use the same information from the form the user fills out.

Also, any help to help clean up the javascript I currently have would be great! I find it very cumbersome to add multiple scripts when I am sure it can be accomplished with one.

Here is the codepen link for what I have done so far:

https://codepen.io/jpwerner18/pen/LYNKwVK

```js
$('.meta').on('submit', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('.field').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('field', '');
    $('.modal #' + id).text($(this).val());
    $('.modal').show();
    $('.overlay').fadeIn(200);
  });
});

$('.modal-close').on('click', function() {
  $('.overlay').fadeOut(200);
  $('.modal').hide();
});

$('.user').on('submit', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('.field').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('field', '');
    $('.modal #' + id).text($(this).val());
    $('.modal-user').show();
    $('.overlay-user').fadeIn(200);
  });
});

$('.modal-close').on('click', function() {
  $('.overlay-user').fadeOut(200);
  $('.modal-user').hide();
}); <
/script>


<
script >
  function copyClipboard() {
    var elm = document.getElementById("meta");
    // for Internet Explorer

    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
      var range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(elm);
      range.select();
      document.execCommand("Copy");
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      // other browsers

      var selection = window.getSelection();
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(elm);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
      document.execCommand("Copy");
    }
  }

function copyClipboard() {
  var elm = document.getElementById("user");
  // for Internet Explorer

  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(elm);
    range.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    // other browsers

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(elm);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("Copy");
  }
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.overlay-user {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #afafaf;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal-user {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #afafaf;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal-close {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form id='fields' class="meta" autocomplete="off">

    <label for='field1'>TWAMP IP 1:</label>
    <input type='text' class='field' name='twamp1' id='twamp1'><br>

    <label for='field2'>TWAMP IP 2:</label>
    <input type='text' class='field' name='twamp2' id='twamp2'><br>

    <label for='field2'>Device TID:</label>
    <input type='text' class='field' name='tid' id='tid'><br>

    <br>
    <div><span>Step 3 - Generate the meta Data Files</span></div><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
  </form>

  <br>

  <form id='fields' class="user" autocomplete="off">
    <div><span>Step 4 - Generate the User Data File</span></div><br>

    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
  </form>


  <div class='overlay'>
    <div class='modal'>
      <button class='modal-close'>X</button><br>
      <div id="meta">
        #cloud-config<br> chpasswd: { expire: False }<br> ssh_pwauth: True<br>
        <br> bootcmd:
        <br> /etc/hosts
        <br> - ip link set ens4 down<br> - ip link set ens4 name eth0<br> - ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0<br> - ip link set eth0 up<br> - ip link set ens4.4001 down<br> - ip link set ens4.4001 name eth0.4001<br> - ifconfig eth0.4001 0.0.0.0<br> - ip link set
        eth0.4001 up<br> - ifconfig eth0.4001:2 <span class='field' id='twamp1'></span><br> - ifconfig eth0.4001:2 <span class='field' id='twamp1'></span> netmask 255.255.255.254<br> - ifconfig eth0.4001:4 <span class='field' id='twamp2'></span><br> -
        ifconfig eth0.4001:4 <span class='field' id='twamp2'></span> netmask 255.255.255.254<br>
        <br>
        <br> write_files:
        <br> - path: /opt/firstboot/etc/firstboot.conf<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;permissions: '0644'<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;owner: root:root<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;content:|
        <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MNG_IF='ens2'
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <button onclick="copyClipboard()">Copy</button>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class='overlay-user'>
    <div class='modal-user'>
      <button class='modal-close'>X</button><br>
      <div id="user">
        instance-id: iid-54cd3a6c7bcf<br> local-hostname: <span class='field' id='tid'></span>-twamp<br> network-interfaces: |<br> auto ens2<br> iface ens2 inet dhcp<br> auto ens4<br> iface ens4 inet static<br> address 0.0.0.0/24<br> auto ens4.4001<br>        iface ens4.4001 inet static<br> vlan-raw-device ens4<br> address 0.0.0.0/24<br> auto ens4.4001:2<br> iface ens4.4001:2 inet static<br> vlan-raw-device ens4<br> address <span class='field' id='twamp1'></span>/31 auto ens4.4001:4<br> iface ens4.4001:4
        inet static<br> vlan-raw-device ens4<br> address <span class='field' id='twamp2'></span>/31
      </div>
      <button onclick="copyClipboard()">Copy</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to choose which submit button is chosen when clicked. I really just want to have one form and depending on the button that is chosen, a configuration will be generated with information on that the user input.